# How to install C Compiler to Eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse, compiler-construction

I have install the C/C++ CDT Version of Eclipse.
After making a HelloWorld.c file and get the code in there I get an error of "Launch failed. Binary not found".

I found in google that my Eclipse miss the compiler and I install MinGW on my computer and add the path to env variables (tested it with "gcc -v" in cmd and succeded).

But poorly it get the same Launch Failed error - any ideas, what step I forgot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things to check:
1.) MinGW tools are installed as well.  Make sure you have the C compiler and the Make program
2.) Check your Environment variables.  Make sure both the compiler and Make are on the path.
3.) Eclipse is a temperamental beast at times, don't lose heart :-)
4.) If you're looking for a good IDE (without care for ideological concerns), might be worth looking at Bloodshed C++ IDE and Visual C++ 2010 express (or whatever they call their free version).
5.) Check the options menu in Eclipse to make sure it's looking at the correct environment variables for finding the Path.

Comment: Bloodshed works, but there are better free IDEs out there. If you're not gonna go for VC++, I'd recommend Code::Blocks. It's free, updated regularly, and supports compilers other than GCC if you want to switch.

Comment: @Maulrus - Fair point.  It's been years since i used Bloodshed..i moved to Visual Studio for windows and Eclipse/Vi for linux.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, the simplest setup for eclipse on windows these days is cygwin - it seems to have been updated more recently than mingw, and works better.

Go to http://www.cygwin.com/, download the installer, select the default directory of c:\cygwin. Select 'All users'.

When it offers a list of packages, select 'gcc', 'binutils' and 'make' under the 'devel' category.

Add c:\cygwin\bin to your windows environment PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Eclipse knows where to find your gcc compiler. An easier way would be to use EasyEclipse until you are more comfortable with your dev env.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to move from the MinGW gcc to the CygWin gcc - all the C++2011 works and others say it is a better option too.  Download the CygWin binaries etc. and then open up Eclipse.

In project properties, C/C++ Build -> Environment and set the CYGWIN_HOME variable.  This worked fine for me on Eclipse Kepler Windows 7 (64Bit)

[image: screen shot of setting environment variable]

I also put the cygwin bin directory at the front of my Windows PATH variable.

Full details here:
http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcdt_o_home.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing [wascana](http://code.google.com/p/wascana/). It automatically set up GNU compiler for you on Windows.